# What is the best way to validate a entity id that is passed a parameter for a GET request?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I've been passing entity IDs and trying to make sure their valid.  What is the optimal way to do this?

I currently do it like this:  `url: /path?var=1234 #var is Kind X`

```
this_var = self.request.get('var')
try: 
    obj = X.get_by_id(this_var)
except ValueError:
    return
if not this_obj:
    return
```

I use the `try` to make sure it's an integer and the `if` to see if it was successful, is there a better way of doing this check?

Comment: Use NDB and safe keys: ndb.Key(urlsafe=encoded_key).get()

Answer (score 0):

how about this method?

```
# validating the integer
this_var = self.request.get('var')
try: 
    this_var = int(this_var)
    obj = X.get_by_id(this_var)
except ValueError:
    return
```